# How to exit while loop using keypad?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, keypad

I can't seem to be able to escape a while loop using a keypad button. I've tried the solution from this thread: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=79932.0

Here's my code:

```
void alarm(){
  char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();

  while (customKey == NO_KEY){
    customKey = customKeypad.getKey();
    lcd.noDisplay();
    delay(750);// change for faster flash
    lcd.display();
    delay(750);// change for faster flash
  }
  lcd_home_screen();
}
```

I tried both == and != for the while (customKey == NO_KEY)

Additional info:
I am calling this alarm function from another function inside my Loop.
Here's the complete code:

```
void loop() {
  // keypad
  char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();    
  if (customKey == 'A'){
    main_program(5);
  }
}

int main_program(int duration){
  timer(duration);
  alarm();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using `delay()` within your `while` loop you have to ensure that you are pressing the key at the precise moment it is read.

You should not use `delay()`.

Instead take a look at the *BlinkWithoutDelay* example in the IDE. And also consider implementing a [Finite State Machine](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/finite-state-machine) to know both if you're blinking and what state you're blinking currently is in.

Comment: Your solution of BlinkWithoutDelay makes a lot of sense and is more reachable for my level of knowledge, thank you. My blockage now is the problem that I cannot bool the lcd.Display and noDisplay functions. In the BlinkWithoutDelay example, the code checks for low or high pin output, but in my case I have to check if my lcd is on Display or noDisplay. How can i check that? I'll post the new code if what I just wrote is not clear.

Comment: Nevermind, I made it work with a dummy boolean variable. BlinkWithoutDelay was the way to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Majenko's answer,  you can create some enumeration types for the states, e.g.

```
enum EAlarmState 
{
   On,
   Off
};

EAlarmState _alarmState = EAlarmState::Off;

enum EBlinkState
{
    BlinkOn,
    BlinkOff,
};

EBlinkState _blinkState = EBlinkState::BlinkOff;

unsigned int long _lastBlinkTime = 0;
```

The `_blinkState` and `_lastBlinkTime` state will not be checked when `_alarmState` is off.

Now you can use something like this to check the states and the keypad (pseudo code):

```
void loop()
{
    checkKeypad();

    switch (_alarmState)
    {
    case EAlarmStateOn:
       if (millis() - _lastBlinkTime) >= 750)
       {
          `Blink off code`
          switch(_blinkState)
          {
          case EBlinkStateOn:
             _lastBlinkTime = millis();
             'Blink off code'
             _blinkState = EBlinkState::Off;
             break;

          `same for case EBlinkStateOff'
             break;

          default: // Error
             break;
          }
       }
```

And also create state checking and changing for the alarm itself.

It looks like a lot of code (and it will be), so split it in sub functions. But the most important is that the code is fairly easy to read (and thus maintain).

Comment: I tried to copy/paste your code, but since I don't understand what is going on, I could not make it work. I pasted the top part of your code before the Setup() function, and the bottom part in the while loop inside my alarm() function. I now face the following error msg "expected initializer before '_blinkState'

Comment: I forgot the semi colon after the second enum. I don't have a compiler at hand

Comment: You also should get rid of the while statement. Don't block your code for long or indetermined time.